# Using a global wrapper template in Express/Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've had a quick skim of the Jade documentation and I can't seem to figure out how to apply a wrapper to all templates that I output.

How is this usually done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want [template inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#template-inheritance):

```
// layout.jade
!!!5
html
  body
    block content
```

The `content` block is what you define in all templates that are going to inherit the layout template:

```
// index.jade
extends layout

block content
  h1 Hello World!
```

When you render `index.jade`, this is the result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

So in `layout.jade`, you set up all common elements like JS/CSS, headers/footers, etc.

Comment: Gah, I knew about this. Why didn't I put 2 and 2 together?! Thankyou